# requireJS worked for one plug-in, but not another

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931220/using-requirejs-for-plugin-that-exports-multiple-function-to-jquery), and got one plug-in to work. Now, I'm trying to get another plug-in to work using the solution for the first plug-in, but that solution isn't working.

I'm trying to get [this plug-in](https://github.com/javierjulio/textarea-auto-expand/blob/master/examples/jquery.textarea_auto_expand.js) to work, but the chrome console spits out this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined :3000/js/libs/textarea_auto_expand.js:41
```

My code is this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
      jquery: '/js/libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.3',
     underscore: '/js/libs/underscore/underscore-min',
     backbone: '/js/libs/backbone/backbone-min',
  //text: '/js/libs/text'
 templates: '../templates'
 ,sockets: '/socket.io/socket.io' 
 ,rangyInputs: '/js/libs/rangyinputs-jquery-1.1.2'
 , textareaAutoExpand: 'js/libs/textarea_auto_expand'

},
shim: {
  'Backbone': ['Underscore', 'jQuery'],
  'sockets': {exports: 'io'}, 
  'rangyinputs-jquery': {deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$'}, 
  'textarea_auto_expand': {deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$'}

} 
});

  require(['jquery', 'router', 'libs/a_myLib/keydownHandler', 'libs/textarea_auto_expand' ], 
function($, router, keydownHandler, ta_ae){
$("body").on("keydown", "textarea", keydownHandler);
router.initialize();
$("textarea").textareaAutoExpand();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, you used path name **jquery**, but specified **jQuery** in you Backbones deps:

```
'Backbone': ['Underscore', 'jQuery'],
```

Again, here is working example of main.js

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        jquery : 'jquery-2.0.3',
        'rangyinputs-jquery' : 'rangyinputs-jquery-1.1.2',
        textareaAutoExpand: 'js/libs/textarea_auto_expand'
    },
    shim : {
        'rangyinputs-jquery' : {deps : ['jquery'], exports : '$'},
        'textarea_auto_expand': {deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$'}
    }
});


require(['jquery', 'rangyinputs-jquery', 'textarea_auto_expand'], function($) {
    console.log('Type of $.fn.textareaAutoExpand ' + typeof $.fn.textareaAutoExpand );
    var t = $('<textarea/>').textareaAutoExpand();
    $('body').append(t);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets rid of the console error, but the text-areas aren't actually expanding.

Comment: Updated example. They do expand in this case.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I thought it might be because the textareas I was using were dynamically added, so I tried directly adding one to the HTML. No Luck. I think I'm just going to switch to browserify, since this is a really small project that doesn't need to be too performant.